# How to search a column value in another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want search cell A value in cell B and arrange accordingly in cell C.

How to achieve this?

For exmaple A1= abcd xyz
and B10 = abcd so B10 is exist in A1 so I want to arrange this B10 value in C1

Comment: What if you are looking for bcd in abcd xyz? Still a positive match?

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula.

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1)),B1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Can i use =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A:A)),B1,"") if I want to search in full B cell

Comment: You can use then you have to enter this formula s array formula means you have to press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` after entering formula to cell.

Comment: If you need partial match then you can use `MATCH()` function with wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can type below formula in Cell `C1`. If B10 is found in A1, it will put B10 value in C1. Otherwise, it will put "".

```
=IF(SEARCH(B10,A1) > 0,B10,"")
```

**UPDATE : If value is not present, it will lead to #VALUE error. You can try below solution**

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B1,A1),B1,""),"")
```

@Harun24HR, has provided more cleaner solution to the problem.

Comment: This will produce error if search value is not found.

Comment: @Harun24HR, Sorry. I did not specifically addressed the scenario of #VALUE error problem. I have updated my answer. I saw your solution. Upvoted the same.